# Make Attribute appear as hyperlink

Tags: acumatica

I have an attribute with the case number from another instance. I have to make it appear as a hyperlink so user can click on it and it can direct visit to that case.

Any suggestion.

It adds up the link to all row, but I need hyperlink only on Case Number attribute. (see below image).
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by attribute? Do you want a Link inside a grid cell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the link inside a grid cell.

First make an action in your graph with it's primary DAC:

```
public PXAction<MyPrimaryDAC> viewCase;
```

Primary DAC can be found in the graph:

```
public class MyGraph : PXGraph<MyGraph, MyPrimaryDAC>
```

Make an event handler for the action in your graph to open the case:

```
[PXButton]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewCase(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    // Assuming the case you want is already set as current
    // Otherwise lookup case by ID if necessary
    CRCase crCase = CRCases.Current as CRCase;

    if (crCase != null && crCase.CaseID != null)
        PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(this, crCase, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Declare the action in the CallbackCommands of your ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" 
                     PrimaryView="MyDataView" TypeName="MyNamespace.MyGraph">
        <CallbackCommands>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="ViewCase" DependOnGrid="gridCase" Visible="False" />
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Finally use LinkCommand attribute on your grid field to bind the action:

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="MyField" LinkCommand="ViewCase" />
```

Comment: I need to make hyperlink for only particular cell not the whole grid column. It is only for one of the attribute value in Case screen.

Comment: Set MatrixMode="True" property on the grid. In your dataset or in fieldselecting event return either the Link content or null.

Comment: Added screenshot above in main question. I setup MatrixMode for Grid as well as GridColumn, but not sure if I using correctly. It just creates hyperlink to entire column instead of only one attribute. 
<px:PXGridColumn MatrixMode="True" LinkCommand="ViewAcumaticaCase" DataField="Value"

Comment: OK I get it, don't think LinkCommand is flexible enough for that though. Is there any grid in Acumatica which has a similar link presentation?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask this as a new question. Someone might know how to do it.